# Why PhpStorm does not show latest available packages for some project?

Tags: phpstorm

Usually PhpStorm 2023.3  shows all latest available packages in project
composer.json file. But in the laravel/PHP project I work now PhpStorm 2023.3 does not show
latest available packages :
[image]

Under settings I found block :

[image]

But I do not know are this options relative to my issues here ?

Comment: Everything should work out-of-the-box when "Check for available package updates" option is enabled. Did you notice if "Checking for Composer updates..." message appears in a status bar when you close/open a "composer.json" file?

Comment: I do not see any "Checking for Composer updates..." message when I open "composer.json" file in this project or even in other projects, where I see last available packages in "composer.json" file. Is it some additive option ?

Comment: BTW, "Check for available package updates" option is disabled on Settings page. Not sure why ?

Comment: Hm, I might be missing something but it is enabled on a screenshot above, isn't it?

Comment: Enabled, but grayed - that raised a question

Comment: Strange, I have never seen it grayed (apart when no composer.json is configured). What seems also weird is that no radio button is active under "Execution". Would it help if you click on "composer executable" to select it?

Comment: @duck_in_hat, If I select "composer executable" "Check for available package updates" option is enabled and selected, but nothing was changed in  composer.json file and new packages hints are visible...